# mostrar números no utilizados

Tags: mysql, sql

En mi base de datos tengo usuarios que eligen un numero del 1 al 999 ese numero es único, lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que muestren los números no utilizados aun , que condición me podría ayudar a mostrar en una tabla los **números no utilizados**

```
SELECT nroUsuario from USUARIOS

+-----------+
| nroUsuario| 
+-----------+
|1          |
|3          | 
|6          |
+-----------+
```

necesito que muestre una tabla que muestre los números que no se encuentran en la db hasta el 999 ejemplo :

```
+-----------+
| nroUsuario| 
+-----------+
|2          |
|4          |
|5          | 
|6          |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Pregunta _medianamente_ relacionada: ¿cómo lo asignas cuando lo eligen?

Comment: @Alfabravo lo asignan mediante un formulario de html y se guarda en una tabla donde estan sus datos junto a eso el numero

Comment: Vale, pero cómo garantizas que no se repita?

Comment: Puedes poner tus tablas con tus datos para ver como es aunque sea los 20 primeros datos y ese numero es clave primaria y autoincremental imagino no? para que no se repita eso imagino yo al menos @Alfabravo

Comment: Dirás que tan fastidioso preguntando. En realidad es porque, dependiendo de cómo lohagas, lo más fácil es que reuses la info que ya tienes al asignar, identificando lo que ya sabes que _hace falta por asignar_. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, respondamos íntegramente en MySQL:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE nrosRestantes()
  BEGIN
    declare i int;
    set i=1;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS nros;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE nros(
      nro INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY                            
    );
    while i<1000 DO
      INSERT INTO nros VALUES (i);
      set i=i+1;
    end while;
    SELECT * FROM nros
      WHERE nro NOT IN (
        SELECT nroUsuario FROM usuarios
      );   
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Con un `CALL nrosRestantes();` obtendrás la lista de los números que aún no han sido asignados.

Comment: error al crear el procedimiento : #1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca '' en la linea 3

Comment: @Sebastian ten en cuenta que no lo puedes copiar tal cual porque no sabemos nada de tus datos por lo que  debes adaptarlo a tus tablas o modificar tu pregunta añadiendo tus tablas y los datos  de la tabla

Comment: Puedes ser por los `DELIMITER`, te modifico la respuesta a algo más genérico

Comment: claro  antes del create ``DELIMITER $$`` y luego después del end; ``DELIMITER ;``

Comment: ahora me aparece un error sin excepción,  Sorry an unexpected error happened!

Comment: Pues algo tendrás mal en el servidor, aquí funciona: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9qSVZ4xfBESe2J3mava3Ec/0

Comment: perfecto @DavidJP solo remplace los \\ por **$$** y funciono perfecto muchas gracias!

Comment: Ése es mérito de @JavierG.Raya, me alegra que te haya servido su idea. Teóricamente podría ser cualquier par de caracteres pero es verdad que el slash, como se usa como carácter de escape, puede dar problemas... Ya siento no haberme percatado

Comment: no hay de que @DavidJP para eso estamos para echar un cable :)

Comment: en realidad el tuyo esta bien pero tiene un error de sintaxis tu ``END\\`` esta mal ya que en programación eso indica omisión de lo siguiente como el \$a en php eso omite el $ y lo escribiría tal cual  por lo para que funcione en tu caso debes poner ``DELIMITER //`` y en el ``END //`` incluido ese espacio, me acabo de dar cuenta al ver tu código @DavidJP

Answer (score 2):

Tal vez peque de pensamiento único y, aún a riesgo de equivocarme, creo que lo que estás buscando es algo así:

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');
$r=[];
$rs=$conn->query("
    SELECT nroUsuario FROM usuarios;
");
while($ri=$rs->fetch_row())
    $r[]=$ri[0];
$txt=null;
$txt.='<form>'
    .'<select name="nro">';
for($i=1;$i<=999;$i++)
    if(!in_array($i,$r))
        $txt.='<option>'.$i.'</option>';
$txt.='</select>'
    .'<button>Seleccionar</button>'
    .'</form>';
echo $txt;
```

A partir de los números seleccionados por los usuarios que vas guardando aquí:

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios(
  id_usuario int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  usuario varchar(31),
  nroUsuario int
  );
INSERT INTO usuarios VALUES
  (NULL,'Juan',1),
  (NULL,'Pedro',5),
  (NULL,'Mateo',9),
  (NULL,'Lucas',12);
```

Espero que el formulario lo estuvieras generando desde PHP, si fuera en JS, ya nos lo comentas y buscamos una solución.

Comment: Y ¿qué pinta aquí el php?

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev tienes toda la razón, pero de alguna forma tendrá que generar el formulario... :)

Comment: Sí, @DavidJP, pero eso ya es cosa suya...

Comment: Y si usa java en el backend? O node? O python? Creo que lo correcto sería ceñirse a las etiquetas proporcionadas, y si quieres proporcionar un ejemplo, siempre puedes usar pseudocódigo o un esquema. Por cierto, un detalle simplemente, cuando se comparte código (especialmente con alguien que no tiene mucha experiencia) utilizar nombres de variables con significado real hace que sea más fácil de entender el código! Para alguien sin experiencia, ver `$rs`, `$r` y `$ri` puede resultar confuso, puesto que no tienen por qué entender el significado de dichas abreviaturas. Un saludo :)

Comment: @Benito-B estás en lo cierto, respondo a continuación íntegramente en MysQL. ¡Gracias por la aportación! :)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba algo así para sacar los números que no se hayan usado:

```
SELECT nroUsuario from USUARIOS WHERE 
nroUsuario IN (SELECT @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number FROM USUARIOS JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r WHERE @curRow < 100) 
AND nroUsuario NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT nroUsuario FROM USUARIOS);
```

Comment: Esta consulta siempre dará vacío, ¿no? :D

Comment: Demonios, tienes razón. Vaya metedura de pata...

Comment: toma @EvgeniEnchev https://www.db-fiddle.com/ con eso puedes hacer pruebas de MySQL yo lo uso un montón y me va genial, espero que te sirva amigo :)

Comment: La opción de la variable me gusta porque es mucho más compacta que el procedimiento almacenado, pero no conseguí generar una lista de números si la tabla `usuarios` aún no tiene 999 registros... :(

Comment: @DavidJP no tiene 999 registro de momento pero ya el usuario ira metiendo datos

Comment: @JavierG.Raya es cierto que el tiempo arregla muchas cosas pero, en este caso, terminarías asignando números consecutivos para lo que te serviría un simple `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Fíjate en que únicamente te ofrecería tantos números como usuarios hayas introducido: 1 usuario te ofrece hasta el 1, 2 el 2, porque el 1 ya lo habrá pillado el 1, y así sucesivamente...

Comment: También tienes razón no caí en el auto_increment @DavidJP

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev: en lugar de escribir "editado", pon solo la consulta "a probar", ¡y no olvides explicar su funcionamiento! La respuesta debe ser útil no solo para el autor de la pregunta, sino también para los demás usuarios que tengan un problema similar.